# Can't create MySQL Boolean Field Using flask-sqlalchemy & flask-migrate

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have a working flask app with few models. The `User` model is as follow...

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    bio = db.Column(db.String(255))
    patterns = db.relationship('Pattern', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

Now I want to add a new boolean column to the model. I'm utilizing MySQL as a database. I have tried the following...

```
invited = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=0)
```

but when I runt `flask db migrate` I get the following...

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
```

I also tried

```
from sqlalchemy import BOOLEAN # also with Boolean
...
invited = db.Column(BOOLEAN, default=0) # also with Boolean
```

but get the same error. Reading MySQL documentation found out that MySQL doesn't have boolean type rather `TINYINT`. But reading this [Github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/277) thread I understand that the Boolean class will turn into `TINYINT` based on the dialect. So I did the following...

```
from sqlalchemy.dialect.mysql import BOOLEAN
```

and still I get the same error when `flask run migrate`. Seems like Alembic can't see the changes in the model.

Is there a way to create a boolean field in `mysql` utilizing `flask-migrate` and `flask-sqlalchemy`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below, I'm assuming Flask migrate is not recognizing `db.Column(BOOLEAN, default=0)`.

```
a_boolean_field = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
```

I've just tested it and above works and Flask-Migrate was able to detect it.

Comment: It does work with `sqlite3` but not with `mysql`. When I change to `mysql` I get the following... 
`INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.`
`INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column

invited = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
```

this should work with MySQL.